# Can't re-share a previously shared drive

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, home-sharing

I have several shared drives on my pc, connected to a home LAN. When I wanted to rename one of those shared drives I received an "Incorrect function. Can't share drive" error. As a test, I plugged in an external USB drive and tried to share that and received the same error message.

I've tried several fixes from this site and others, but nothing has worked. I don't want to reinstall Windows 7 and do not have any reset points on which to fall back (mea culpa).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run ( <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ) `compmgmt.msc`

There in "Shared folders", you should see all shares. Find that one you renamed and delete it.